# vi is frozen after search on arch linux

Tags: shell, vi

I'm on Arch Linux live USB. I'm using vi to open an 18kb text file containing a single line of json. I did a search with `/` and hit a block partway through the file represented by an `@` symbol. Then, when I press `n` to go to next match, the editor freezes. The cursor is on the command line with `/` highlighted and the cursor is glitching.

The editor doesn't respond to :q, esc, Ctrl+Q, Ctrl+C, Ctrl+Z, Ctrl+D, Ctrl+L, Ctrl+/

When I press Ctrl+S, the cursor begins blinking normally but Ctrl+Q makes it start glitching again.

Alt+F2 then `kill -9 [pid]` works to get out. But I'd like to know what the problem with the file is.

Upon opening the file, I noticed an incomplete last line error message displayed on the command line. But no line too long error. Also, vi would not scroll past the @.

The file is on an HDD mounted externally through USB. The OS is on a USB stick.

Comment: Did you try Ctrl-L (usually referred to as `<C-l>` to redraw the screen?

Comment: I tried it now and it didn't do anything

Comment: How about `<Esc><Esc>:q!<Enter>`?  (Does this command even show up when you type it?)

Comment: That doesn't do anything either.

Comment: Does the command show up when you type it?  Does your screen update?

Comment: No, the cursor is on the command line with `/` highlighted.

Comment: The last thing I did was esc the search

Comment: I'm in the chat room also. I'm considering turning the machine off, if there's nothing else I can do.

Answer (score 1):

The `@` mark indicates a line too long to display.  vi still has to keep track of the position before/after the line, and if it's long enough you will certainly notice "some" slowdown as it reads the data and tries to move past that line.

Further reading:

- [How do you prevent vim from showing an at symbol (@) when a line doesn't fit on screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4621798/how-do-you-prevent-vim-from-showing-an-at-symbol-when-a-line-doesnt-fit-on)
- [vi : Line too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276317/vi-line-too-long)
- [Line too long on VI. Commands alternatives to navigate last lines of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18531298/line-too-long-on-vi-commands-alternatives-to-navigate-last-lines-of-a-file?lq=1)